# Spring batch jobstep example

Tags: java, spring, parallel-processing, spring-batch

I am trying to run multiple jobs in parallel in spring batch.After lot of search in google i came across JobStep.Has anyone used JobStep can explain how to use this to run jobs in parallel or is there any other way to run 2 independent jobs in parallel i.e when i start the batch 2 jobs should start running in parallel
.My requirement is like

```
 <batch:job id="JobA" incrementer="runIdIncrementer">
            <batch:step id="abc">
                <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                    <batch:chunk reader="ReaderA" writer="WriterA" processor="ProcessorA" />
                </batch:tasklet>
          </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <batch:job id="JobB" incrementer="runIdIncrementer">
            <batch:step id="def">
                <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                    <batch:chunk reader="ReaderB" writer="WriterB" processor="ProcessorB" />
                </batch:tasklet>
          </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
```

When my application starts both jobs should start running.Is it possible to do so using spring batch

Edit:i even tried this way

```
<batch:job id="ParallelJob" incrementer="runIdIncrementer" restartable="true">
            <batch:split id="parallelprocessing" task-executor="taskExecutor">
                <batch:flow>
                    <batch:step id="ParallelJob.step1" >
                            <batch:job ref="JobA" job-launcher="jobLauncher" job-parameters-extractor="jobParametersExtractor"/>
                    </batch:step>       
                </batch:flow>
                <batch:flow>
                    <batch:step id="ParallelJob.step2" >
                            <batch:job ref="JobB" job-launcher="jobLauncher" job-parameters-extractor="jobParametersExtractor"/>
                    </batch:step>       
                </batch:flow>
            </batch:split>
        </batch:job> 


<batch:job id="JobA" restartable="true">
        <batch:step id="abc">
            <batch:tasklet >
                <batch:chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" processor="processor"  />
            </batch:tasklet>
      </batch:step>

    </batch:job>

<batch:job id="JobB" restartable="true">
        <batch:step id="abc">
            <batch:tasklet >
                <batch:chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" processor="processor"  />
            </batch:tasklet>
      </batch:step>

    </batch:job>
```

I am facing exception saying 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.core.Job] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3:ParallelJob,JobA,JobB.I am starting job using  commandLineJobRunner and passing jobId asParallelJob

Comment: Do you want just to be able to execute the two jobs at the same time as a part of a job? or just to start the two jobs as soon as your application starts ? or you want to execute the two jobs at the same time in a arbitrary way ?

Answer (score 0):

Definition:

```
<batch:job id="globalJob">
<batch:split id="StepOne">
    <batch:flow>
    <batch:step id="step1" >
        <batch:job ref="jobRef1"/>
    </batch:step>

    </batch:flow>
    <batch:flow>
    <batch:step id="step2">
        <batch:job ref="jobRef2"/>
    </batch:step>
    </batch:flow>
</batch:split>
</batch:job>
```

Execute the jobs whenever you want:

```
@Autowired
JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("globalJob")
Job globalJob;

 @Override
public void executeGlobalJob() throws NoSuchJobException, JobInstanceAlreadyExistsException, JobParametersInvalidException {

    try {
        jobLauncher.run(globalJob,new JobParameters());
    } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
        throw new JobInstanceAlreadyExistsException("JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException",e);
    } catch (JobRestartException e) {
        throw new JobInstanceAlreadyExistsException("JobRestartException",e);
    } catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e) {
        throw new JobInstanceAlreadyExistsException("JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException",e);
    }
}
```

}

Execute the jobs after the application starts just set the property:

```
spring.batch.job.names=globalJob
```

Comment: i have edited my question,Can you please check @damian

Comment: I just test your config and the only problem I saw is that the batch steps can't have the same id: <batch:step id="abc">, change the second one for something like <batch:step id="abc2">. Steps can't have the same id even if they are in different jobs.

Comment: I have solved the issue .The problem is caused by class which am not using anymore.@damain thank you